# What particles can be used with 気にしない?

Tags: particles, expressions

I would like to say "I don't mind that," or "That doesn't bother me," but I'm not sure what particles to use for 気にしない when I would like to specify both a subject and an object. These are the combinations that sounded plausible to me:

- 「それは私が気にしません。」
- 「それが私は気にしません。」
- 「それは私に気にしません。」
- 「私はそれを気にしません。」

Which (if any) of these is correct, and if multiple are permissible, what differences in nuance might exist?

(P.S. I understand that in many cases, the 私 or それ or both could be dropped, but let's assume my case really does call for them.)

Comment: I think you meant to ask this with 気になる...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

気にする is transitive (する is transitive here), so you use を:

> 私は(が*)それ**を**気にしません。

---

The を can be replaced by は when それ is thematic or contrasted:

> それ**は**私は(が*)気にしません。

---

As an aside: Grammatically speaking you can use それ**が** with intransitive 気に**なる** (なる is intransitive), as in:

> (私は/私には)それ**が**気に**なり**ません。

---

*For the difference of が and は, this thread might be of help:

- [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/9831)